# Sort data in Axios response and set as useReducer payload

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, reducers, use-context

I'm calling data from an api into my react app using axios, like so:

```
const adapter = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4000",
});

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await adapter.get("/test-api");
  return response.data;
};
```

This runs in a context, and I have a basic reducer function that I pass to the context:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  error: false,
  data: [],
  errorMessage: "",
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    case ACTIONS.FETCH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        errorMessage: "Error loading data",
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The data I'm returning from my api is shaped like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name 1",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "klqo1gnh",
          "name": "Item 1",
          "date": "2019-05-12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Name 2",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "klqo2fho",
          "name": "Item 1",
          "date": "2021-05-05"
        },
        {
          "id": "klro8wip",
          "name": "Item 2",
          "date": "2012-05-05"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I've written a simple function that finds the item whose nested array, `items` here, has the earliest date, using `moment`:

```
const sortDataByDate = (items) => {
  return items.sort((first, second) => {
    if (moment(first.items.date).isSame(second.items.date)) {
      return -1;
    } else if (moment(first.items.date).isBefore(second.items.date)) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  });
};
```

I then fetch everything in this function:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await getData().then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS,
          payload: response,
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCH_ERROR });
    }
  }, []);
```

I then run `fetchData()` inside a `useEffect` within my context:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);
```

All this to say, here's the problem. My `sortDataByDate` function works sporadically; sometimes the data is ordered correctly, other times it's not. What I'd like to do is fetch my data, sort it with `sortDataByDate`, and then set the `payload` with that sorted data, so it's sorted globally rather than on a component level. Inside my `App` it seems to work consistently, so I think that I have missed something on a context level. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a small improvement: There is a moment function called isSameOrBefore which could save you the second if

Comment: Can you setup a small codesandbox example? Then I will have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort inner items first and get the earliest date:

```
  const sortDataByDate = (items) => {
    return items.sort((first, second) => {
      if (moment(first.items[0].date).isSame(second.items[0].date)) {
        return -1;
      } else if (moment(first.items[0].date).isBefore(second.items[0].date)) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: This mostly worked, however it's not actually sorting them when I update the payload in `initialState.data`. I sorts them once the page is refreshed, but I need this function to run every time the `data` changes.

Comment: Well can't you just apply the function inside the reducer? Sadly your example doesn't show us where you are calling the function.

Comment: You could call the sorting function inside your component. So every time you update your state, the component gets re-rendered and you re-sort your data.

Comment: @mleister it's not a good practice to apply a function inside a reducer. The reducer has one main job is getting action and updating the state.

Comment: thanks soufiane, that ended up working, and I moved it out of the reducer.